# Properly embedding custom frameworks into a project in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

It's getting quite frustrating with Xcode 5 here. All I'm trying to achieve is embedding some custom Cocoa frameworks into my project and create two versions of the app, one for the Mac App Store and one for a custom Online Store (so that when building for the MAS there'll be a folder called Debug (MAS) so I can distinguish it from the other version).

I embedded three frameworks into the project (only god knows why only one project can have another one embedded at a time, to hell with this limitation) and added their products in the "Link binary with libraries" and "copy frameworks" build phase. The finished built products are at the default location in the Library.

Now here's the thing - every time I'm using custom build configuration files other than "Debug" and "Release", the frameworks are NOT copied to the custom build folders but instead just go into "Debug" and "Release" regardless of any build options of the main app. Also, the frameworks are always built using "Debug" and are no longer connected to the current build mode (test, archive, etc.). To cut a long story short, this is a huge mess with file paths and obviously a lot of bugs concerning custom frameworks and custom build configurations.

Now my question is - there has to be an official or working way of maintaining an Xcode project that is both distributed over the MAS and a custom online store (two versions) and has at least one custom framework embedded. How do all other developers have solved this problem, I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and if I do, sorry for putting the blame on Xcode but something's for sure: Xcode's path management with external components is a chaos and the cause for unlimited mailing list and forum posts...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create separate targets for the MAS & non-MAS app. You can add additional targets to build the custom frameworks and make the different targets dependent on each other (as necessary). Once this is all setup (properly) then building any of the targets will build any dependent targets (with the same build flags). And AFAIK there's nothing preventing an Xcode project from including multiple sub-projects so I haven't a clue why you believe this to be the case.

Comment: Once a project is embedded into two other Xcode projects and one is trying to open both, a message pops up saying "Cannot open XYZ.xcodeproject because it is already open in another workspace", that was the message I was talking about. Concerning the frameworks and building with the same flags - here's the problem: If I assign an Xcode configuration file to my project named anything other than "Release" or "Debug" (e.g. MAS-Release.xcconfig) all embedded frameworks are NOT building inside MAS-Release, instead they'll always go into the default Debug or Release folders.

Comment: And once they do, Xcode leaves me with an error saying "Literal or preprocessor issue" when importing the framework usinng #import <.../...> in my prefix file, complaining that it can't find the framework.

Comment: That's a different issue; You have to have the "user header search paths" set to include your frameworks headers folder. (and you should be using #import ".../..."; or @import framework (if you have modules turned on).) And I wouldn't embed it as a project… I'd make it a target and set the dependencies accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what you're basically saying is, the project embedding feature should not be used even though Apple recommends it in their docs?

Comment: Seriously! I'm so tired of spending countless hours reading "official" Apple documentation only to find out that the way they suggest is the wrong way. I mean … wha … how?! I'm at the point where @Toby is. I think. There are so many "directives" and path variables that I don't even know what I'm doing anymore. And by the way, not once does the documentation mention "user header search paths." How are those different than "Header search paths" or "Framework search paths" in Xcode 5? I made a framework. I would assume that I would need to tell Xcode my framework path, but that's not right?

Comment: #include <system/header.h> // System header search path(s)

Comment: #include "user/header.h" // User header search path(s)

Comment: "Framework search paths" are where the compiler & linker are going to look for… Frameworks!

Comment: >>"So what you're basically saying is, the project embedding feature should not be used even though Apple recommends it in their docs?". Nope, I'm telling you how I would do it. The project embedding feature is convent when you don't own the other project but when you do is there any value added in having it in a separate project instead of just using another target in the same project? I don't think so.